# How to style the items inside a ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, styling

Is it possible to change the color of [the items inside a `ComboBox`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZXYD.png) in JavaFX?

I want to change the background color of each item to black and its text to white, and to green and white when hovering.

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> govs;

public void initialize() {
    ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(   
         "Ariana",
         "Beja",
         "Ben Arous",
         "Bizerte",
         "Gabès"
    );   
    govs.setItems(options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this cannot be done by applying CSS rules to the node, you have to supply your own [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) implementation to the combobox.

```
comboBox.setCellFactory(param -> new ComboBoxListCell<String>() {{
    setTextFill(Color.WHITE);

    Background blackBackground = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, null, null));
    Background greenBackground = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, null, null));

    setBackground(blackBackground);
    setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
        setBackground(greenBackground);
    });
    setOnMouseExited(event -> {
        setBackground(blackBackground);
    });
}});
```